# Does telegram instant view increase webpage hits?

Tags: telegram, instant-view

If I use Telegram messenger instant view feature, for each click on instant view, will the unique page visitor of my website increase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't. Telegram will cache the result.

Comment: I imagine this information is or will become available via API, in which case the number of "hits" is really dependent on the implementation